# Flexbox is not display space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've used flexbox before with justify-content: space-between; and it worked just fine, but I'm trying to apply it to a different class and it's just not working.

This one works:

```
.contenido-header {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This one does not work:

```
.contenedor-anuncios {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I would really appreciate your input :)

Comment: Check the width of the 2nd class's container. The code looks like it should work find which leaves the possibility of there not being enough width for the elements inside to space out

Answer (score -1):

Your `.contenedor-anuncios` should work fine, unless it's inside another flexbox. If that's the case, add one more property to it:

```css
.contenedor-anuncios {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1; /* take as much horizontal space as possible */
}
```